# Spyder is showing garbage on console when trying to "print" Sympy expressions

Tags: python-3.x, ipython, spyder, sympy

I use Sympy for some calculations and during debugging or after the script has run in want to inspect some variables. The IDE is Spyder, so i use its console. I think it is called IPython, but i am not sure about this.

As all the variables used within the script, they all remain available after the script stopped. I just write the name of a variable to the console and expect that the content of the variable is displayed.

This works nicely for "normal" variables. But when it comes to Sympy objects, i can see only garbage:

[image: Variable explorder and IPython console]

What am i doing wrong? Can i change this behavior? Can i make Spyder/IPython write the Sympy expressions using normal ASCII characters, It does not need to reformat the expressions in some not easy readably ASCII "art". If i need a nice representation of the expressions i can use a Jupyter notebook anyway.

Comment: You can use `init_printing()` to enable the sympy printers. It also has many different options for controlling the printing. Most likely the garbage you see is to do with foreground/background/transparent settings somehow.

Comment: Thank you, executed init_printing() in the console and now the expressions are rendered nicely. But can i get rid of this rendering at all? I dont want those expressions to be rendered that way, i feel more comfortable when they are written as i typed them in the code.

Comment: As I said there are many options to `init_printing` (see the docstring). I don't use spyder but something like `init_printing(use_latex=False)` maybe.

Answer (score 1):

I deactivated "Symbolic mathematics" in Preferences / IPython console / Advanced settings.